# Show data using moving table AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to develop a table that recieves a JSON, my goal is to display that data into a table showing only the first 4 JSON entries, if has more than 4 items it will disappear the first entry and show the 5th entry in 10 seconds intervals. Like a image carousel but moving vertically. Ive added the html tag `<marquee>` but that way it moves the content but the table fields get different size from the header table.

view.html

```
<html>
<body ng-app="schoolApp">
<div id="report" ng-controller="classesController">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Students</strong></h4>
</div>
<br>
</div>
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered ">
<marquee direction="up">
     <tr ng-repeat="student in classArray">
        <td align="center">{{student.number}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{student.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{student.age}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{student.grade}}</td>
    </tr>
</marquee>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look this example: https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-carousel

Comment: Your question will get more responses if you show what you have tried so far and indicate where you are currently stuck.

Comment: @SteveCampbell After my research ive tried to use a html tag `<marquee>`but that doesnt work the way that i want and I guess that tag is deprecated. I will update my question.

Comment: The problem with the tag marquee is that is not allowed where you are using it. The table only can have as child the tags caption, tr, thead, tbody and tfoot, and nothing else. Because the use inside the table, you are getting unexpected behavior like the different size between the column content and the headers.